# Alternative to owncloud, which can store data on external sdcard on android

Tags: android, self-hosted, owncloud

I would like to have self-hosting dropbox alternative.

Up to now I use owncloud and the owncloud android app.

Unfortunately it is not possible to store the data on the external sd-card on android. See: https://github.com/owncloud/android/issues/10

Now I am looking for an alternative.

Needed features:

- self-hosting
- server must be open source
- client: open source would be nice, but no a "must".
- android app must be able to store the data on an external sd-card
- User management
- Sharing of directories via link or to other authorized users.

I don't care for the name of the server. Maybe using the owncloud server with different android app is enough, or switching both (client and server software) is needed.

Comment: Would it be an option to stay with your current setup, and just use a different tool to keep things in sync? There's e.g. FolderSync where you can define folder pairs to sync. I'm using this with SD card storage just fine. And it can talk to ownCloud (and a lot of other sources).

Comment: @Izzy yes, using a different android app is a solution. It would nice if you could write an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you stay with your current setup – but just replace the sync app on Android. For that part, I use **[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite)**¹ – which allows you to define "folder pairs" (for each, one local folder and its corresponding remote folder). I use this app with folders located on my SD cards (on multiple devices), and it works fine. *FolderSync* supports multiple cloud providers, including ownCloud/nextCloud, so this should perfectly match your needs.

[image: Providers] [image: FolderPairs] [image: Options]
<sup>*FolderSync:* supported clouds, FolderPairs, options (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite); click images for larger variants)</sup>

For each FolderPair, you can define not only the sync interval, but also whether it should only "fire" when on (a certain) WiFi, when charging, and more. I've set mine all to "manual", and control sync via *Tasker*, which it supports as well.

---

¹ <sub>the link goes to the ad-supported "free" version, while I'm using [the paid one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full)</sub>

Comment: FolderSync is not open souce. But that's ok. I updated the question. For me it is important that the server is open source. I guess there are plenty of alternatives to FolderSync, this way the fear of vendor lock-in is not here.

Comment: @guettli Oops – I've missed the "Open Source" part! And that to me! Unfortunately, in the FOSS section it looks pretty empty. Check for yourself (watch out for the F-Droid and IzzyOnDroid icons as well as for Github links as indicators) in my list: [Synchronizing Files and Folders](//android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync) – oh, there is one (not tested by me, so I cannot say if it fits): [Cirrus for owncloud](//play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synox.android) ([Github](https://github.com/skymania/Cirrus)).

Comment: You could also try the Nextcloud client. But I'm afraid that one will make no difference.